# Histogram bars disappeared when added a min value to the y domain - D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have used [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1624660) to create a histogram with variable-width bars. It looks OK but my first x value point starts at 1200, so I want to change the min domain from 0 to my minimum x value.

```
x.domain([0, d3.max(bins.map(function(d) { return d.offset + d.width; }))]);
```

I have replaced the 0 with `d3.min(bins.map(function(d) { return d.offset + d.width; }))]`. The x axis render as expected although the bars disappear. I even tried to hard-code the actual min x value but I am getting the same results.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your complete code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the example is using the same scale for both the *position* of the bars and the *width* of the bars.  When you change the domain, the position shifts over as expected, but the widths will now be negative values.  Which throws an error and the bars don't get drawn at all.

Original code for bar width:

```
svg.selectAll(".bin")
  .data(bins)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bin")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.offset); })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.width) - 1; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.height); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.height); });
```

Because your x domain no longer starts at zero, you'll need to figure out the width of the bar based on the difference between the positions of it's left and right edges:

```
  .attr("width", function(d) { 
         return x(d.width + d.offset) - x(d.offset) - 1; })
```

(The `- 1` at the end is just padding.)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)